# Are math operator names like \gcd available in other languages?

Tags: math-mode, languages

I'm writing a text in Dutch in which I want to use the *greatest common divisor*. In English, I could use something like `$\gcd(123,321)$`. However, in Dutch, we call the function *grootste gemene deler*, ggd. Of course, I could use `$\text{ggd}(123,321)$` (in fact, for this I wouldn't even need math mode, but suppose this is inside a larger equation). But isn't there a way to get the mathematical commands the translated?

Comment: Do you ask, if there is a translation of the output of `\gcd` into other languages?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Either that or a way to use a function like `\ggd`, using some kind of package that would provide this function based on the language. I'm sorry, I didn't quite know how to put this question into words.

Comment: You _do_ need math, as it is math and to match style with other math. To make the spacing correct do not use `\text` but something like `\DeclareMathOperator{\ggd}{ggd}`.

Comment: You could use `babel`, but you have to provide the translation for supported languages yourself. I don't know that there some translations available

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen that works, great! Supposing there are no translations already available you can make it an answer.

Comment: The best solution would perhaps to have the standard operator `\gcd` display differently according to context.

Comment: @Bernard yes, this would allow one to easily copy equations between documents in different languages. However, as I understand the other comments, this is not possible, right?

Comment: `\let\gcd\relax\DeclareMathOperator\gcd{ggd}`

Comment: Well I have a very simple idea (certainly too simple): define a math operator for each language (such as `\ggd`or `\pgcd` in French), then declare `\let\gcd\ggd`. It could be written in some config file for each language. There are not so many finctions.operators whose names differ from one language to another. But maybe there are drawbacks to this way of doing things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an (easy) approach to change the output of the `\gcd` operator according to the current language settings. It's not perfect, the spacings could be better, definitely.

Add other languages at will ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[ngerman,english,dutch,strings]{babel}

\newcommand{\gcdname}{}

\StartBabelCommands{dutch}{extras}%
\SetString{\gcdname}{ggd}%
\EndBabelCommands

\StartBabelCommands{ngerman}{extras}%
\SetString{\gcdname}{ggt}% Groesster gemeinsamer Teiler
\EndBabelCommands

\StartBabelCommands{english}{extras}%
\SetString{\gcdname}{gcd}% Greatest common divisor
\EndBabelCommands


\let\gcd\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\gcd}{\gcdname}%



\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\(\gcd{144,12}\)

\selectlanguage{english}

\(\gcd{144,12}\)

\selectlanguage{dutch}

\(\gcd{144,12}\)


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is possibly/probably the best option, as it allows copying math between documents in a different language and doesn't add a whole load of new commands, like [`\DeclareMathOperator{\ggd}{ggd}`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199362/are-math-functions-like-gcd-available-in-other-languages/199366#comment462964_199362) would.

Comment: I think there should be some `math-language` option, as one might want to have text in German, say, but however stick to US notations for functions.

Comment: @Bernard: Do you mean an option to the `\ggd` command?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I would rather think of a .sty file, with translations  for each language — more or less the way localisations work in `cleveref`.

Comment: @Bernard: That's an interesting idea... Will you provide the French translations? (My knowledge of French is..., say, limited ;-) )

Comment: I can do that. But at at the moment, I can see only the names for gcd and lcm (pgcd and ppcm, or p.g.c.d. and p.p.c.m. in old style). Do you have a more complete list of such operators that can change with language?

Comment: @Bernard: I have to think about that... for sure, some names will only change in some languages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16908/discussion-between-bernard-and-christian-hupfer).

Answer (score 6):

If you load the package `amsmath`, you can easily define new math operator names using that package's `\DeclareMathOperator` macro. E.g.,

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\ggd}{ggd}
```